# Localize iPhone App name in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, localization

When I select the Info.plist file so that the App name can be localized and try to build the project, the build fails with an error saying that the Info.plist file cannot be found.

If I change the Info.plist file path to `PROJECTNAME/en.lproj/Info.plist` it builds, but the App's name is not localized; if I run on a Portugues iPhone it has the English name.

Why?

Thanks,

RL

Comment: Is that a Portuguese iPhone with an English locale, or a Portuguese iPhone with a Portuguese locale?

Comment: Port iPhone with English language.

Comment: Change the iPhone locale to Portuguese and the app should then show in Portuguese. Where the phone is physically from is not important.

Comment: the question is that i want is to have the app in english, as the default language. What I want to know is how to localize the Apps name, in Portuguese, French, German, ... .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add  `InfoPlist.strings` to your project and localize it. Put this in different languages:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution I found tonight / localized app names / xcode 4.5:

- First change the name of you app:
       Folder Supporting Files 
                `InfoPlist.strings` (Portuguese)
- By selecting `InfoPlist.strings` (Portuguese), its content will appear in the window
  right next to it.
- Put that code inside:

  > ```
  > "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Title in Portuguese";
  >
  > "CFBundleName" = "Title in Portuguese";
  > ```
- Then SAVE the file.
- Go to the iOS simulator, and change language to anything but Portuguese.
  This will permit to reset the app icon.
- Run your app.
- Change your iOS language to Portuguese. You should then see the
  Portuguese name.

Answer (score 3):

iPad and iPhone have different space available for displaying the app name, probably it comes from their icon size (57px vs. 72px)

So sometimes what fits perfectly on iPad is truncated on iPhone.

You can have different display names on iPad and iPhone like this:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName~iphone" = "iPhone display name"
"CFBundleDisplayName~ipad" = @"iPad display name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the file inspector
Add localize language under you localize section
Change your CFBundleDisplayName to your desire bundle app language
[This](http://bit.ly/eSpWjm)  may help you out

Comment: The question is that when I do that, I keep the reference in the en.proj to the ${Product Name}, and on the Portuguese, I change to the portuguese name. When I run the App in my iPhone, instead of appearing the Portuguese name, appears the english one.